# Add an item to a matlab class

Tags: matlab, class

I have two classes defined: library and book. The library has name and books. Book has a name and and an author. I have a method in library class which adds book to the library. They are as follows

```
classdef library
properties
    name
    books=book.empty
end
methods 
    function self=library(val1)
    self.name=val1;
    end
    function addbook(self,item)
        self.books(end+1)=item;
    end
end
```

end

and the book

```
classdef book
    properties 
        author
        title
    end
    methods
        function self=book(val1,val2)
            self.author=val1;
            self.title=val2;
        end
    end    
end
```

Now I define

```
lib1=library('Leib')

book1=book('A','T')
```

When I want to add this book to my library using my addbook method it does not wrok. The library stays empty

```
lib1.addbook(book1)

lib1 = 

  library with properties:

     name: 'Leib'
    books: []
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st you have an error in your `addbook` method - it is not returning self, i.e.

```
function self = addbook(self,item)
  self.books(end+1)=item;
end
```

You are also seeing the difference between a handle class or a value class, see [here for mathworks explanation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

To resolve it either:

```
 lib1 = lib1.addbook(book1);
```

or change you library class to derive from a handle class

```
classdef library < handle
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab objects are (by default) not references. This means that you need to explicitly return and set a copy of a object.

```
function newLib = addbook(self,item)
    self.books(end+1)=item;
    newLib = self;
end
```

Then:

```
lib2 = lib1.addbook(book1);
```

It should be noted that lib1 and lib2 are **different** objects with the same class, i.e. you return a copy of lib1 with the modifications by calling addbook. If you wish to have referenced object behavior, subclass from the handle class.